# Restar variable en una BD - SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente duda sobre BD en sql, tengo un valor y queria saber si lo puedo restar directamente de la varible que se encuentra en la BD con una query o te que pedir ese valor, restarlo y despues reemplazarlo en mi BD.

Comment: De poder se puede, pero por favor comparte lo que has desarrollado para poder ayudarte, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es posible por ejemplo: `UPDATE tabla SET campo1=campo1-campo2 WHERE id=2;`
o `UPDATE tabla SET campo1=campo1-25 WHERE id=2;`